# How to search for text in XML and extract it's entire node it belongs to, with python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

what I have is this:

I know that "12345" is present throughout the xml, but under different nodes. I want to search for "12345" and extract the node block it belongs to. So here, "12345" is under "Rating" but elsewhere in the xml it is under "Description".

The code below only searches for Rating but how do I search for "12345" and extract the block it is contained in?

```
       `<Rating action="set">
            <details>12345</details>
            <media>compact disk</media>
            <region>GRE</region>
            <sequence>1</sequence>
            <flag>0</flag>
        </Rating>`
```

`for Rating in root.findall('.//{xmlsheading}Rating'):
    value_found = False
    for details in Rating.findall('.//{xmlsheading}details'):
        if details.text == name:
            value_found = True
            break
    if value_found:
        print ET.tostring(Ratings)`

Comment: You didn't finish your sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this to get the information I need.

Example query return parent node where sub element *akey* = 12345

query is all the parent elements that match that query

```
from lxml import etree


name = '12345'

tree =   etree.parse('C:/Users/file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()


query = root.xpath('//ns:akey[text()="12345"]/..', namespaces={'ns': 'URN:XXX:XXXX:XXX:ADP:0001'})
for parent in query:
    print "" + '\n' + parent.tag
    child = parent.getchildren()
    for kid in child:
        p = kid.tag + " " + kid.text
```